# error in twitter authentication with website in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I'm getting this error while implementing twitter authentication

```
/home/jay/Documents/passport-twitter-master/examples/signin/node_modules/serve-favicon/index.js:38

  if (!path) throw new TypeError('path to favicon.ico is required');
                   ^
TypeError: path to favicon.ico is required

    at favicon (/home/jay/Documents/passport-twitter-master/examples/signin/node_modules/serve-favicon/index.js:38:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jay/Documents/passport-twitter-master/examples/signin/app.js:66:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `favicon.ico` file in your Express configuration, usually `app.js` or `server.js` file.

```
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
```

The file must exist on disk.